# WPF Selecting the Control that should play Storyboard Animation from Code Behind

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, animation

I have created a MainMenu and two Animations: ZoomIn & ZoomOut.
The MainMenu will be filled with Canvas, each containing icons. What I am trying to do, is on clicking a button, that the current visible panel disapear with ZoomOut and clicked Panel appear with ZoomIn.

So far I have managed to call the Animation from Code Behind using this:

```
Dim ZoomOut As Storyboard = DirectCast(FindResource("storyZoomOut"), Storyboard)
    ZoomOut.Begin()
```

But now I want the particular control to animate. Also is it possible to animate two diferent controsl at the same time? like Canvas1 ZoomOut and Canvas2 ZoomIn at the same time?

```
<Storyboard x:Key="storyZoomOut">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="pnlCompras">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="0.8"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0.6"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="0.4"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="0.2"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0.0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="pnlCompras">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="1.04"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="1.09"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="1.15"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="1.3"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="pnlCompras">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="1.04"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="1.09"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="1.15"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="1.3"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="pnlCompras">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="pnlCompras">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
```

thanks all for your help!

Comment: just to make it clear, I have various Canvas controls each one on top of the other. And will be using IsVisible property to bring them to view.

Comment: Instead of using a Storyboard, you could directly animate a property by calling [BeginAnimation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms590761.aspx) on the control. This may of course be impractical if the Storyboards contains multiple animations. If you post the XAML of your Storyboards, we might find out.

Comment: Yes, it does contain multiple animations, opacity & size. There is also one for position which I can easily remove as it does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the `Storyboard.TargetName="pnlCompras"` setting from all the animations in your Storyboards and then run a Storyboard on any control by [Storyboard.Begin(FrameworkElement)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms605709.aspx).

```
Dim ZoomOut As Storyboard = DirectCast(FindResource("storyZoomOut"), Storyboard)
ZoomOut.Begin(someControl)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use these lines in your event

```
Dim ZoomOut As Storyboard = DirectCast(FindResource("storyZoomOut"), Storyboard)
ZoomOut.Begin( --Control-- )
```

or

Test with this other line

```
DirectCast(FindResource("storyZoomOut"), Animation.Storyboard).Begin()
```